# Wait for ComponentDidMount to finish loading in highest component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I manage user auth in my `AppRouter.js`which is my highest component.

Here is how it works:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.getUser()
}

getUser(history = undefined) {
  const { cookies } = this.props
  let jwt = cookies.get(this.state.cookieName)
  if (!jwt) return null

  AuthApi.getCurrentUser(jwt).then(response => {
    if (response !== undefined) {
      this.setState({
        email: response.email,
        userId: response.id,
        firstName: response.first_name,
        lastName: response.last_name,
        phoneNumber: response.phone_number,
        randomString: response.random_string,
        jwt: jwt
      })
      if (history) history.push('/')
    }
    else {
      // user has cookie but cannot load current user
      cookies.remove(this.state.cookieName)
      this.setState({
        email: undefined,
        firstName: undefined,
        lastName: undefined,
        phoneNumber: undefined,
        randomString: undefined,
        jwt: undefined,
        userId: undefined
      })
    }
  })
}
```

My problem is, I also call `componentDidMount()` in children components and the code there depends on the result of my `AppRouter`'s `componentDidMount()` output.

Here is an example with my `MyOrdersPage.js` component that receives `AppRouter`'s state as props:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/api/v1/orders/' + this.props.currentUser.userId)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
        this.setState({
            orders: response.data
        })
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
```

However, `AppRouter`'s `componentDidMount()` finishes loading after `MyOrdersPage.js` 's `componentDidMount()`. Hence, `this.props.currentUser.userId` is `undefined` when `MyOrdersPage.js` 's `componentDidMount()` runs.

How can I change my code so that `componentDidMount()` from children components only loads when `componentDidMount()` is done loading in `AppRouter.js` ?

Comment: Even if you run `componentDidMount` of highest component last, it would still not have the props, since API call is asynchronous. What you would want to do here is show and loader and load content only after API call completes

Comment: hi @BoyWithSilverWings, thank you for your help ! How can I achieve that exactly in my code ? I don't really get how I could do so as API calls are in two different components

Comment: don't render children until all data is retrieved. To achieve that just introduce simple flag on parent's state like `this.state.isReady` that is initially `false`  and after data is loaded is set to `true`. Then you could do `{this.state.isReady && .........}` in your `render()`

Comment: make sense; if you want to write a detailed answer, I'll accept it as the valid solution. Thank you very much !

Comment: don't see anything extra to add. in the future once you are tired from handling loading on every component in the same way it may be useful to use [react-load](https://github.com/jxom/react-loads) or implement something similar on your own. But by now better start with simpler solution based on flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @skyboyer mentionned in the comments, I added a state `isReady`, set to `false` by default, to the parent component. It turns `true` once the API call is done loading:

```
AuthApi.getCurrentUser(jwt).then(response => {
    if (response !== undefined) {
      // do something
    }
    else {
      // do someting else 
    }
  }).then(() => this.setState({isReady: true}));
```

And in the `render()` method:

```
{this.state.isReady &&
        <div>...</div>}
```

Moreover, implementing [react-loads](https://github.com/jxom/react-loads) could be a good idea too.